# How can I simulate contamination delay in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, delay

Propagation delay is simple to implement:

```
  Out <= '1' after 3ns;
```

I tried to add contamination delay as such:

```
Out <= '1' after 3ns;
Out <= 'X' after 1ns;
```

so that `Out` would become undefined and then switch properly. However, in simulation I only observe the final assignment. [I'm using MultiSim to simulate, but this [Quartus II link](http://altera.us/support/kdb/solutions/rd08242000_5040.html) suggests it's normal to only observe the final assignment]

Is there a good way to simulate contamination delay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Out <= 'X' after 1 ns, '1' after 3 ns;
```